# Put element above another for small screen

Tags: css

Trying to put a sidebar on top of content text for small screens.

What I tried did not work.

```css
@media(max-width: 820px) {
  .head {
    display: -webkit-box;
  }

  .text > .sidebar {
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
      <div class='head'>
      <aside class='sidebar'>
      </aside>
     </div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to do?

Comment: @user11145458 I'm sorry if you feel as if I had provoked you in some way, but I did not downvote your question, nor did I break any of the SO policies by asking you to elaborate. I'm glad that you've found the answer you were looking for, though I do encourage you to take another look at the timestamps for each of the answers, both of which predate my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of problems:

- An erroneous `<body>` tag (simply remove this).
- A selector (`.text > .sidebar`) that will never match the target element.
  You don't actually need *any* styling on `.sidebar`, so I also just removed this.
- A logical error -- `.head` contains no `order`; I assume you want this *below* `.sidebar` in the mobile view, meaning it is *`.head`* that would need `order: 2` (not `.sidebar`).

Once all of these are corrected, you simply need to give `.container` `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`, and the swap will work as expected.

This can be seen in the following (simplified) example:

```css
@media(max-width: 820px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .head {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='head'>
    <div class="text">
      TeXt
    </div>
  </div>
  <aside class='sidebar'>
    wordS
  </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

using flex you can change the `flex-direction` to `column` then change the `order` of the flex items as needed.

you can also use `grid` in combination with `grid-template-areas` to set and rearrange the order of grid cells as you see fit. for example, in conjunction with `@media`

```
...
grid-template-areas:
  "content"
  "header";
...

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  ...
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "content";
  ...
}
```